# Why can't I capture more than one digit in substring?

Tags: regex, pcre, named-captures

I am creating regex to extract various fields from logs files. I have created one regex using some tools and its almost complete. the only thing is for one field its extracting only one digit instead of full number.  for better understanding I have saved it to below link.

[My Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYjX7j/1)

Pattern:

```
/(?=[^P]*(?:ParNew|P.*ParNew|PSYoungGen|DefNew))^(?:).*(?P<ParNew_before_1>\d)K\->(?P<ParNew_after_1>\d+)K\((?P<young_heap_size>\d+)K\), (?P<par_new_duration>\d+\.\d+) secs\] (?P<ParNew_before_2>\d+)K\->(?P<ParNew_after_2>\d+)K\((?P<total_heap_size>\d+)/
```

String:

```
146372.273: [GC146372.274: [ParNew: 378633K->88155K(419456K), 0.0313803 secs] 9893391K->9602913K(12478080K), 0.0320299 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]
```

Current Output:

```
Full match      `146372.273: [GC146372.274: [ParNew: 378633K->88155K(419456K), 0.0313803 secs] 9893391K->9602913K(12478080`
Group `ParNew_before_1`     `3`
Group `ParNew_after_1`      `88155`
Group `young_heap_size`     `419456`
Group `par_new_duration`    `0.0313803`
Group `ParNew_before_2`     `9893391`
Group `ParNew_after_2`      `9602913`
Group `total_heap_size`     `12478080`
```

Expected Output:

```
Full match      `146372.273: [GC146372.274: [ParNew: 378633K->88155K(419456K), 0.0313803 secs] 9893391K->9602913K(12478080`
```

> Group `ParNew_before_1`       `378633`

```
Group `ParNew_after_1`      `88155`
Group `young_heap_size`     `419456`
Group `par_new_duration`    `0.0313803`
Group `ParNew_before_2`     `9893391`
Group `ParNew_after_2`      `9602913`
Group `total_heap_size`     `12478080`
```

In above example: Group `ParNew_before_1`   extracting only one digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things  I'd like to note here:

- The lookahead should be placed after `^` (it will make more sense to check its pattern at the start of the string only)
- The `\d` won't match more than 1 digit, add `+` after it to match 1 or more
- `.*` is too greedy, use lazy `.*?`.

Use

```
^(?=[^P]*(?:ParNew|P.*ParNew|PSYoungGen|DefNew)).*?(?P<ParNew_before_1>\d+)K->(?P<ParNew_after_1>\d+)K\((?P<young_heap_size>\d+)K\), (?P<par_new_duration>\d+\.\d+) secs\] (?P<ParNew_before_2>\d+)K\->(?P<ParNew_after_2>\d+)K\((?P<total_heap_size>\d+)
 ^^^                                           ^  ^                      ^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AYjX7j/2)

Also, you do not need to escape `-` that are not inside character classes.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside when you have a long pattern, do not hesitate to use the x modifier *(for the "free-spacing" mode)* and eventually the quoting feature `\Q..\E` *(to figure spaces and special character without escaping them)* to make it more readable:

```
/
^
(?=
    [^PD\n]* (?>[PD][^\nPD]*)*? \b
    (?: ParNew | PSYoungGen | DefNew )
)
[^\n\d]* (?>\d+[^\n\d]+)*? \b
(?<ParNew_before_1>  \d+      ) K->
(?<ParNew_after_1>   \d+      ) \QK(\E
(?<young_heap_size>  \d+      ) \QK), \E
(?<par_new_duration> \d+\.\d+ ) \Q secs] \E
(?<ParNew_before_2>  \d+      ) K->
(?<ParNew_after_2>   \d+      ) \QK(\E
(?<total_heap_size>  \d+      )
/x
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgGvGY/1)